# How to automate time scale (x-axis) limit adjustement with GGPLOT?

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I am having the following data set:

`head(data, 10)`

```
     date      time            datetime varX varY
1  2020-06-24        0S 2020-06-24 00:00:00     0  0
2  2020-06-24    15M 0S 2020-06-24 00:15:00     3 27
3  2020-06-24    30M 0S 2020-06-24 00:30:00     8 12
4  2020-06-24    45M 0S 2020-06-24 00:45:00    29 76
5  2020-06-24  1H 0M 0S 2020-06-24 01:00:00    10 22
6  2020-06-24 1H 15M 0S 2020-06-24 01:15:00     0  0
7  2020-06-24 1H 30M 0S 2020-06-24 01:30:00     0  0
8  2020-06-24 1H 45M 0S 2020-06-24 01:45:00     0  0
9  2020-06-24  2H 0M 0S 2020-06-24 02:00:00     0  1
10 2020-06-24 2H 15M 0S 2020-06-24 02:15:00    14 39`
```

`tail(data, 10)`

```
          date       time            datetime varX varY
471 2020-06-28 21H 30M 0S 2020-06-28 21:30:00     0  0
472 2020-06-28 21H 45M 0S 2020-06-28 21:45:00     0  0
473 2020-06-28  22H 0M 0S 2020-06-28 22:00:00     0  0
474 2020-06-28 22H 15M 0S 2020-06-28 22:15:00     0  1
475 2020-06-28 22H 30M 0S 2020-06-28 22:30:00     0  0
476 2020-06-28 22H 45M 0S 2020-06-28 22:45:00     0  0
477 2020-06-28  23H 0M 0S 2020-06-28 23:00:00     0  0
478 2020-06-28 23H 15M 0S 2020-06-28 23:15:00     0  0
479 2020-06-28 23H 30M 0S 2020-06-28 23:30:00    37 86
480 2020-06-28 23H 45M 0S 2020-06-28 23:45:00    24 72
```

I want to plot the daily varX for several days togeter in the same plot.

I am using the below code:

```
    p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = datetime, y = varX)) + 
      geom_area() + facet_grid(vars(date))
    p
```

***THE PROBLEM:***
The daily plots don't have the sought xlimit.
[Varx over 3 different days, but the xlim for all days are the same][1]

I am hoping to have something like the above photos but with xlim restricted of the daily varX.

Anyhelp??
Thanks
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/unEKb.png

Answer (score 0):

This can work:

```
#Code
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = datetime, y = varX)) + 
      geom_area() + facet_grid(vars(date),scales='free_x')
```

Or:

```
#Code2
ggplot(data, aes(x = datetime, y = varX)) + 
  geom_area() + facet_wrap(vars(date),scales = 'free_x')
```

Comment: I added scales=free_x and also tried scale = free. But ti did not work!